# $_REQUEST can not get query parameter

Tags: php, request, superglobals

Payment is successful but it is still displaying error, the Transaction with this ID is not found.
I'm performing the transaction form 
              https://pay.digiwallet.nl/test-transaction
This is the PHP code

```
    <?php
    //IDEAL CHECK
    if(isset($_REQUEST['trxid'])) {     // this is not getting the value form my payement system.

    $trx = $_REQUEST['trxid']; 

    $bbdata = array(
        'rtlo' => '144891',
        'once' => 1,
        'trxid' => $trx,
        'once' => 1
    );

    // send a request to example.com (referer = jonasjohn.de)
    $iresult = PostRequest(
        "http://www.xyz/ideal/check",
        "http://www.xyz//",
        $bbdata
    );
```

I just want TRXID done. Which is not accessed successfully from another page of payment pay.digiwallet.nl payment system.

[Animation of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5q3K.gif)

Comment: Try using print, print_r or use error_log to log the values at appropriate places. If it still does not help, please include your upstream code. What you have highlighted is in the middle of action. What happens before or during the code you have attached?

Comment: // START IDEAL CHECK
                                 // PROBLEM START - PROBLEM IS HERE
if(isset($_REQUEST['trxid'])) {

$trx = $_REQUEST['trxid'];

$bbdata = array(
    'rtlo' => '151309',
    'once' => 1,
 'trxid' => $trx,
 'once' => 1
);
                   // PROBLEM END

Answer (score 0):

You should not trust `$_REQUEST` to get variables as described in the doc

> The variables in $_REQUEST are provided to the script via the GET, POST, and COOKIE input mechanisms and therefore could be modified by the remote user and cannot be trusted. The presence and order of variables listed in this array is defined according to the PHP [variables_order](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) configuration directive.

Otherwise, I would suggest you check out variable orders set in the `php.ini` file.

I would recommend to get a variable from the url using `$_GET['trxid']`.

Comment: $_GET['trxid'] Ive tried it with POST and GET both. but it is not working...
iam using test-payment system to test my website.
but unfortunatily its not correctly working

Comment: Did you try using `var_dump($_GET)` or `var_dump($_POST)` before the `if` statement? Would you show us the debugging results?